# WPF application stop working with CLR20r3 error when sending email

Tags: c#, wpf, email

i have WPF application that developed with .NET 3.5.
i tried to run the application on Windows Vista PC.
the application is well running till the part it needs to send email then the application is stoped with the following error:

```
Description:
Stopped working

Problem Signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   yesmonitor.exe
Problem Signature 02:   1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03:   54c730d7
Problem Signature 04:   mscorlib
Problem Signature 05:   2.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06:   53a124a5
Problem Signature 07:   f50
Problem Signature 08:   7
Problem Signature 09:   N3CTRYE2KN3C34SGL4ZQYRBFTE4M13NB
OS Varsion: 6.0.6002.2.2.0.768.2
Local ID:   1037
```

i have also .NET 3.5 framework install on the PC also:

```
Visual C++ Redistributable 2013
Visual C++ Redistributable 2012
Visual C++ Redistributable 2008
Visual C++ Redistributable 2005
```

my code of sending mail is:

```
MailAddress From = new MailAddress("mymail", strIsTestPass + " - " + errorType);
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

mail.From = From;
mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.To.Add("mymail");
mail.Subject = "subject";
mail.Body = "body";
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
NetworkCredential basicCredential = new     NetworkCredential("mail", "password");
smtp.Credentials = basicCredential;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

by the way it works on Win7 OS PC.
what can be the issue and how can i solve it?

Comment: Is it possible to provide a stack trace? The error message indicates an unhandled exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code inside try catch and set your google account setting "Access for less secure apps" to On.

```
try
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

    mail.From = new MailAddress("example@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("example@gmail.com);
    mail.Subject = "email subject";
    mail.Body = "Email body here";
    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail", "password");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception)
{

    throw;
}
```